# How to handle multiple $lookup and large number of columns in $project in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregate

I have almost 4-5 tables between which I need to join. I have completed that using `$lookup`, also I don't need all the fields from secondary tables/joined tables. I need all columns of Primary table. so, I wrote `$project` to select the necessary columns.

```
Room.aggregate([{
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "userID",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "user"
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: "areas",
            localField: "area",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "areas"
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$user",

    }, {$project : {

    }  
    }]
```

I was wondering if I can simplify this query anyhow or create in separate location and merge into main query in more readable and easier format.

Also, I need to specify each column in `$project` as I want all columns from Room table and only few columns from joined tables.

**Update**:

Here are my sample Collection definition
Room:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bcc2eb704c952178c4adbcd"
    },
    "userID": {
        "$oid": "5c0d4e9e7377833f3c362a63"
    },
    "roomQTY": 1,
    "roomPrice": 500,
    "area": [
        {
            "$oid": "5bd4a49857e0c023b0dac7b2"
        }
    ],
    "rating": 3,
    "amenities": [],
    "images": [],
    "isFurnished": true,
    "isActive": true,
    "category": {
        "$oid": "5c0c1438ccbc830d248167bf"
    },
    "roomName": "Shree Laxminarayan Residency",
    "person": "4",
    "size": 157,
    "createdDate": {
        "$date": "2018-10-21T07:45:59.492Z"
    },
    "updatedDate": {
        "$date": "2018-10-21T07:45:59.492Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Ammenities:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bd4b19e57e0c023b0dac7cd"
    },
    "ammenitiesName": "Swimming Pool"
}
```

Category:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c0c1438ccbc830d248167bf"
    },
    "category_name": "PG"
}
```

Desire Output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "5bcc2eb704c952178c4adbcd",
      "userID": "5c0d4e9e7377833f3c362a63",
      "roomQTY": 1,
      "roomPrice": 500,
      "rating": 3,
      "amenities": [],
      "images": [],
      "isFurnished": true,
      "isActive": true,
      "category": "5c0c1438ccbc830d248167bf",
      "roomName": "Shree Laxminarayan Residency",
      "person": "4",
      "size": 157,
      "createdDate": "2018-10-21T07:45:59.492Z",
      "updatedDate": "2018-10-21T07:45:59.492Z",
      "username": "Hardik",
      "areas": [
        {
          "_id": "5bd4a49857e0c023b0dac7b2",
          "areaName": "South Bopal"
        }
      ],
      "ammenities": [
        {
          "ammentiesName": "Swimming Pool"
        },
        {
          "ammentiesName": "Gym"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "code": 200
}
```

Comment: Post your sample collections and the output you need

Comment: ok. sure give me some moment

Answer (score 1):

*[Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)* in  MongoDB 3.6 or above provide pipeline on the joined collection.

```
db.rooms.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
      from: "Ammenities",
      let: {
        amenitiesIds: "$amenities"
      },
      pipeline: [{
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$amenitiesIds" ] }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } }
      ],
      as: "ammenities"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Category",
      let: {
        categoryId: "$category"
      },
      pipeline: [{
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: [ "$_id", "$$categoryId" ] }
          }
        },
        { $project: { _id: 0 } }
      ],
      as: "category"
    }
  }
])
```

You can add multiple pipeline on inner pipeline cool.

Run It your result is waiting for You...

Comment: Sure I will check Pipeline. Jay patidar..jay Sardar